# How to get the existing VPC Quota for an AWS Account using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-vpc

I want to know the existing VPC Quota of an AWS Account using boto3.

Request:

```
response = client.describe_account_attributes( )

print(response)
```

Response:

```
{
    'AccountAttributes': [
        {
            'AttributeName': 'supported-platforms',
            'AttributeValues': [
                {
                    'AttributeValue': 'EC2',
                },
                {
                    'AttributeValue': 'VPC',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'vpc-max-security-groups-per-interface',
            'AttributeValues': [
                {
                    'AttributeValue': '5',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'max-elastic-ips',
            'AttributeValues': [
                {
                    'AttributeValue': '5',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'max-instances',
            'AttributeValues': [
                {
                    'AttributeValue': '20',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'vpc-max-elastic-ips',
            'AttributeValues': [
                {
                    'AttributeValue': '5',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'default-vpc',
            'AttributeValues': [
                {
                    'AttributeValue': 'none',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

In the above Request and Response, I'm getting the EC2 Instance Quota and EIP Quota as well. Likewise, I want a way of using boto3 to get the VPC Quota for an AWS Account without passing any parameter like 'ServiceCode', etc.

I have tried almost all possible ways mentioned in the AWS Boto3 Documentation. But, still I welcome any suggestions/advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Service Quotas** call:

```
aws service-quotas list-service-quotas --service-code vpc
```

The equivalent with boto3 would be:

```py
quota_client = boto3.client('service-quotas')
quota_client = list_service_quotas(ServiceCode='vpc')
```

See: [ServiceQuotas - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/service-quotas.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, John. Will try it and let you know, whether it fulfilled my need or not.